# How can I change Finder's sidebar in macOS Catalina using Bash?

Tags: bash, macos, sidebar, macos-catalina, finder

I want to know how I can change the items in the sidebar of Finder in macOS Catalina using a Bash script.

Editing `$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` or `$HOME/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.finder.plist` with `defaults` or `PlistBuddy` and then restarting Finder (`killall Finder`) or re-logging the user has no effect on the sidebar.

I think the important information regarding the sidebar is stored in the sfl2 ([previously sfl](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/10/recent-items-launch-services-and-sharedfilelists/)) files (maybe only `com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2` matters, not sure) at the `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist` directory, which can be converted to a human-readable format with [`plutil -p file_name.sfl2`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343679).

Though there seems that currently either [no tool exists to edit sfl2 files](https://superuser.com/q/1276241#comment2055241_1276247) or the information that I found is [deprecated](https://github.com/mosen/mysides/issues/14)/obsolete ([`mysides`](https://github.com/mosen/mysides/issues/24), [`sfltool`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/319686), [`FinderSidebarEditor`](https://github.com/robperc/FinderSidebarEditor)).

[image: Finder's sidebar]